# Writing code to: start an R session, run R script, terminate session, repeat

Tags: java, r, terminal

I am looking for a simple "set it and forget it" way, either as a single string of arguments in terminal or a simple Java program, to automate the following:

1) start an R session

2) tell R to source .R files that contain code for lengthy, parallelized simulations

3) terminate the R session upon completion

4) start a new R session

5) tell R to source other .R files

6) terminate the R session upon completion

7) lather, rinse, repeat

My .R scripts will take a total of several days to run, during which I will be out of town and unable to check on them, and if I run them all in the same session there is no possible way for me to avoid maxing out my available RAM.

Thanks!

EDIT: I am running R 2.15.3 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, with 16GB RAM

Comment: Have you tried Rscript.exe? use it in a batch script.

Comment: Why don't you just use a bash script and execute each R script via something like `R --vanilla < ./script1.R && R --vanilla < ./script2.R`?

Comment: `rm(list = ls()); gc()` between sourcing files frees up the memory.

Comment: @sidoh mayby he wants that actions be conditioned on R output and structuring it seems to be simpler from Java level ? But lets ask him.

Comment: @sidoh: that is spot-on what I was looking for! I guess I need to brush up on my terminal commands...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The process of starting and terminating R sessions is handled by using `Rscript`. So write your scripts call them like this:

```
Rscript script_1.R
Rscript script_2.R
...
Rscript script_Inf.R
```

That leaves points 2 and 5... which is a simple matter of putting:

```
source('/home/sc_evans/script_abc.R')
```

...at the head of whatever script(s).

Each script will get its own R session that will terminate upon completion. Put those commands in a batch script and run it.

---

**EDIT**

If I were to do this myself I would forget about using separate scripts though. As long as you're managing memory properly running a single process should work out alright. Divide your processes into appropriate functions:

```
massive_process_1 <- function() {
  x <- do_something()
  saveRDS(x, '/home/sc_evans/results/first_result.rds')      
}

massive_process_2 <- function() {
  x <- do_something()
  saveRDS(x, '/home/sc_evans/results/second_result.rds')      
}

massive_process_1()
massive_process_2()
```

And so on. The next function won't run until the first is completed, and your objects should die in the functions so you shouldn't run out of memory.

Comment: Wow, that was much simpler than I even expected. And yes, I *should* be managing my memory more properly--I do my best to remove all objects immediately after use and call gc() every so often, but that still seems to be inadequate. Oh well, practice practice...

Answer (score 1):

You may look at this solution http://www.rforge.net/JRI

Answer (score 0):

The process of starting and terminating R sessions is not required if we put the longer R script into a loop and put all repeated code section in loop. No need to start a session, you only have to do the first three steps below:

1. Use `write.csv` method [file writing] to save results of your 
   Rscripts.
2. Use `Sys.time(seconds)` for delaying or giving break of short 
   seconds using "base" package
3. By clearing the console and fig workspace through the use of "mise" 
   which is more important package to free the objects space of 
   already executed script.
4. We can also "beepr" package for sound `method:beep(3)`.

My longer script execution does not terminate after this 
I hope this will be helpful for you